# How to show or hide a Panel control if a Repeater control's DataSource object contains no data in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, bind, repeater

I have a Repeater control that's nested inside a Panel control.

```
<asp:Panel id="tags" runat="server">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptTags" runat="server" DataSource="<%# this.DataSource %>">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <span class="tag"><%# Eval("Name") %></span>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</asp:Panel>
```

I set the DataSource attribute of the Repeater control like this **DataSource="<%# this.DataSource %>"** because this code is actually part of a custom Web Control.

I want to show or hide the Panel control depending on whether the DataSource object has any data in it. I had done it like this in the code-behind:

```
    if (rptTags.Items.Count == 0)
    {
        tags.Visible = false;
    }
```

The thing is I want to do this in the ASPX part, something like:

```
<asp:Panel id="tags" runat="server" Visible="<%# ((IEnumerable)DataSource).LengthOrSomething %>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like :

**C#**

```
public void TagsPreRender(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  tags.Visible = (((Repeater)sender).Items.Count > 0);
}
```

**ASPX**

```
<asp:Panel id="tags" runat="server" >
    <asp:Repeater OnPreRender="TagsPreRender" ID="rptTags" runat="server" DataSource="<%# this.DataSource %>" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <span class="tag"><%# Eval("Name") %></span>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</asp:Panel>
```